# Issue with Hash::salt method

Tags: php

I have Hash class as follows:

```
class Hash
{
    public static function make($string, $salt='')
    {
        echo $string.$salt;
        return hash('sha256',$string.$salt);
    }

    public static function salt($length)
    {
        return mcrypt_create_iv($length);
    }

    public static function unique()
    {
        return self::make(uniqid());
    }
}
```

I am calling `method salt()` with command: `$salt=Hash::salt(32)`

Unfortunatelly, function `mcrypt_create_iv` is not working on newer php.

How to redesign Hash class?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Secure hash and salt for PHP passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords)

Comment: A part of. I am beginner and I don't know if I should use hash salt metod or password_hash is enough?

Comment: For hashing passwords `password_hash` is the __best choice__. Do not invent the wheel.

Comment: Ok for hashing, but what about salt? Do I need it at all?

Comment: PHPs builtin password_* functions handle the salt themselves, you don't have to worry about anything apart from calling `password_hash($password)` ans store that as the hashed password in your database.

Answer (score 1):

As [PHP.net says](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-create-iv.php):

> Warning
>   This function was DEPRECATED in PHP 7.1.0, and REMOVED in PHP 7.2.0.
>
> Alternatives to this function include:
>
> random_bytes()

So the alternative you are possibly looking for is `random_bytes($len)`. It can be used the same way as the original deprecated function.

Comment: I tried, but the result is much longer and I can not save it to database

Answer (score 0):

**Warning**
*This function was DEPRECATED in PHP 7.1.0, and REMOVED in PHP 7.2.0.*

Alternatives to this function include:

```
random_bytes()


<?php
$bytes = random_bytes(5);
var_dump(bin2hex($bytes));
?>
```

Comment: You've duplicate the other answer.